# What are these weird characters in my system log? (\x{1B}, U+2026)

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, unicode, character-encoding, character

I was looking into an Ubuntu crash on EC2, so I pulled the system log. What are these weird characters?

I looked the circled one up on https://unicodelookup.com/#%1B/1 and got this: `\x{1B}`

[image]

They are even more obnoxious on VS Code... VS Code says the yellow one is `U+2026`
[image]

Why are these rendering like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+001B is the ESC control code, and it is being used in this case to inject ANSI control sequences into a terminal that supports them.  `<ESC>[0;32m` sets text to green (IIRC) and `<ESC>[0m` returns text to the default color.  Unfortunately they don't redirect to a file well.  Blame the logger.  Different IDEs display control codes differently as you've found.

Read more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

U+2026 is the Unicode character `HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS` (`…`) and it looks like it was used to truncate a portion of the log.

A simple example in Python with the `colorama` module that enables ANSI escape codes.  Note that in the Windows terminal ESC shows as yet another "weird symbol":

[image: colorama example showing untranslated control codes and then translated green text]